Ursula Le Guin - I need help finding something she wrote about anger
I recall years ago reading a short paragraph or couple of sentences she wrote.
The gist of the meaning was that she asked why it is that we always assume that words said in anger are a good guide to help us get to the 'real feelings' someone (the angry person) might have about someone else.
Instead, she suggests that perhaps it is the words said with careful thought and in a calm state that are the truest measure of these things.
I'd very much like to locate the original quote in her own words, but I've looked and looked and can't find it!
My feeling is that it was in one of her collections of essays, or in a forward or introduction to a work of fiction, but I am not completely sure. It could also be within the main text of a work of fiction.
If anyone has any clues as to where it might be, that would be fantastic!

This sounds like something from The Dispossessed, which has a lot of such musings.  But I can't track it down yet.

Possibly * what the sharp-minded, large-spirited, incomparably brilliant Ursula K. Le Guin examines in an essay titled “About Anger,” found in her altogether fantastic nonfiction collection No Time to Spare: Thinking About What Matters”
